# Sortover and sortout events not triggered after element is replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

The middle column should change width when dragging element over it. It does work until I click on replace button which replaces the html of the middle column. Then the events stop being triggered. As far as I know `.on()` should be able to handle such cases, or am I wrong?

This is a simple demo which demonstrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/shuetvyj/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="members-column">
  <div class="sort"> 1 </div>
  <div class="sort"> 1 </div>
</div>
<div id="groupB" class="members-column">

</div>
<div class="members-column">
  <div class="sort"> 2 </div>
</div>
<a href="" id="replace">replace groupB</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".members-column").sortable({
   items: ".sort",
   connectWith: ".members-column"    
 });
$("#groupB").on("sortover", function() {
  console.log('overB');
  $('#groupB').css('min-width','80px');
});
$("#groupB").on("sortout", function() {
  console.log('outB');
  $('#groupB').css('min-width','');
});
$("#replace").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#groupB").replaceWith('<div id="groupB" class="members-column"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you replace the html, the listeners you had attached to the old html are not reattached to the new html.

As a result, your handlers will no longer get called.
To solve this, simply attach the listeners to the new html when you have replaced it.

(jQuery solved this for a while with `live` instead of `on`, which would automatically attach listeners after dom changes) http://api.jquery.com/live/

But `live()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and was removed in 1.9

additionally, removing the column probably also breaks `sortable`'s behavior (since it does not store the selector but the result of the selector when it was first called, and thus retains a reference to the div you removed from the DOM.

In short ; do not remove the column div once you have `sortable` listening to it, just clear or replace its contents

Comment: that may have to do with the fact that removing the column also breaks `sortable`'s behavior. by the looks of it, you would have to reinitialise the entire sortable construction.
on a sidenote, why not just clear the contents of that middle column?

Comment: Yes you're right. In this example I replace only one element but in the real application lots of other things are replaced as well and I'd rather not rewrite code that handles that. So, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead using `replaceWith` use `.html` as below

```
$("#replace").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#groupB").html("");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shuetvyj/5/

Using replaceWith

```
$('body').on('sortover', '.members-column', function() {
     $('#groupB').css('min-width','80px');
    });
  $('body').on('sortout', '.members-column', function() {
     $('#groupB').css('min-width','');
    });
$("#replace").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#groupB").replaceWith('<div id="groupB" class="members-column"></div>');
    $(".members-column").sortable({ items: ".sort",connectWith: ".members-column" });;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shuetvyj/8/

Comment: this works, because it's not removing the div, but clearing its contents leaving the listener and any reference `sortable` has intact.

Comment: Yes, I removed it from answer. I just noticed that